# A deep copy of list of objects instantiates new objects?

Tags: python-3.x, object, deep-copy

First I have written a class I need for some purposes. I have several objects of this class And I have put them in a list. It could be something like:

```
obj0=created_class(0)
obj1=created_class(1)
List_of_obj=[obj0,obj1]
```

Now I need a deep copy of the list:

```
Deep_copy=List_of_obj[:]
```

My question is: this will instantiate new objects from created class?

Comment: it would be trivial to find out: use the `is` operator to inspect the objects. but what makes you think that `[:]` creates a _deep_ copy?

Answer (score 0):

Slicing (`[:]`) does *not* create a deep copy of a list.

```
>>> class K:
...     def __init__(self, v):
...             self.v = v
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return f'<K: {self.v} ({id(self)})>'
... 
>>> l = [K(1), K(2)]
>>> l
[<K: 1 (4556562104)>, <K: 2 (4556562328)>]
>>> l[:]
[<K: 1 (4556562104)>, <K: 2 (4556562328)>]
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> deepcopy(l)
[<K: 1 (4556561880)>, <K: 2 (4556560480)>]
```

Note where the objects' ids are the same and different.

If your class needs special care when copying, you can find out more from the [documentation of the `copy` module in the standard lib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html).